# Should classes that have events always implement IDisposable and set them to null?

Tags: c#, .net, events, dispose, weak-references

Implementing IDisposable in every class that has a c# event/delegate is wrong? The dispose code would simply set all the events of the class to null to prevent leaks¹.
But I don't see anyone doing it, instead I see the weak event pattern.

The only reason I can think of it is: ***Setting a delegate to null only set its value, the memory reference is not removed***

But is that true? From my tests this statament is **false**.

So there's nothing to stop you from doing that, so the only possible answers are:

1. No one does it because in most cases is overgineering/micro-optimization
2. It bloat the code base
3. It is better to not do it for enforcing that all delegates should always subscribe and unsubscribe, rather than relying on dispose.
4. IDisposable is not supposed to be used by managed memory. But don't focus too much on the purpose of IDisposable it's not the point.

*So the true question is* - It would be a good pratice to have a public method² that set all events on a class to null, to ensure that no memory leaks have occurred?

---

¹ Events dont cause true memory leaks, but you get what I mean.
² The method dont need to come from IDisposable could come from other interface, something like ICloseEvent.

Comment: The answer to the bold is indeed false. It would prevent memory leaks in certain specific situations, but the cost of doing so massively outweighs the benefit as you rightly point out. It's unclear exactly what your question is, it seems primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Interesting question. What are the problems and side effects you're expecting from this? As far as I know, IDisposable is mainly intended to release external/unmanaged resources, such as objects created from C++ libraries.

Comment: Well, there is not much use in utilizing IDisposable here. Think about it. The only thing it would do is making the event drop the references to the subscribed event handlers, thus possibly making the instances associated with the event handlers subject to GC. But disposing of an object also typically means you are done with that IDisposable object too, e.g., it also becoming subject to GC. And when it gets collected, any instances still hold by the event would also be collected anyways, assuming nothing else holds onto these instances. Same outcome whether with or without IDisposable...

Comment: Yes good points I will update the question to a more objective one. And add a extra option that I forgot.